# CannotLoadBeanClassException when try to get a bean from applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

i have just started a course about Spring framework and i am struggling getting over this exceiption:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [TrackCoach] for bean with name 'myCoach' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TrackCoach
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:682)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1604)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1080)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:859)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
at com.love2code.springdemo.HelloSpringApp.main(HelloSpringApp.java:9)
```

This is my main class:

```
package com.love2code.springdemo;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class HelloSpringApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //load the spring configuration file
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    //retrieve bean from spring container
    Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", Coach.class);

    //call methods on the bean
    System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());

    //close the context
    context.close();
}
}
```

My TrackCoach class:

```
package com.love2code.springdemo;
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {

@Override
public String getDailyWorkout() {       
    return "Smoke 2 bl's";
}
}
```

And applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- Define your beans here -->  
<bean id="myCoach"  class="com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach">         
</bean>

</beans>
```

Could someone help me out with this please?

Comment: You have a typo in the package name: `luv2code` --> `love2code`

Comment: BTW: Do not use XML for the configuration of Spring. Use the java way. Therer something like that can not happening

Comment: oh god... thank you! i'm just following a course right now and i had struggling with with part.